# How to disable debug server in Qt Creator when building for Android in Release mode?

Tags: android, qt, apk, qt-creator

In Qt Creator when building for android, there is the option of disabling the debug server (this is necessary for releasing applications in the Google Play Store) in "Release" mode. Unfortunately I am unable to sign the application package (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923851/qt-for-android-unable-to-sign-release-version-of-app)) using Qt Creator. However, I am able to sign the package using the Android SDK (`apksigner`). The only problem is that I need to disable the debug server (because of Play Store policy) but Qt Creator disables the option to do when I uncheck "Sign Package". Is there any solution/workaround for this?

[image: Release Mode in Qt Creator]